# jQuery submit vs form submit button with django csrf token

Tags: jquery, django, csrf, csrf-protection, django-csrf

I have a simple form:

```
<form method="post" id="my_form" action="/my_action">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" value="my_token" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If I click the submit button everything works fine but if I use jQuery to submit the form automatically:

```
$(function() {
    $('#my_form').submit();
});
```

I get a "CSRF token missing or incorrect." error.

The strange thing is that when I add:

```
<input type="button" id="activate" />
```

and

```
$("#activate").on('click', function() { ... });
```

Everything works fine. Clicking a button to activate the .submit() delivers the correct functionality, as does clicking the form submit button, but doing it automatically does not.

why?

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
```

Doesn't work either.

Comment: What you see inside your POST data when you inspect the request using browser debug console?

Comment: The token isn't there - but problem solved. There was a submit loop that didn't work on the second round of submit (token on the first submit but not subsequent ones)